# Flask dev server in threaded mode still waits for first thread to finish

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I have a Flask view that sleeps while generating a response to simulate a long request for a web service.  I am running the dev server with `threaded=True`.  When opening three tabs in the browser the second tab doesn't show any updates until the first thread has finished. But the third tab *does* start before the second has finished.  I experienced the same using `processes=4` instead of `threaded=True`.  Why do other threads seem to be waiting for the first to finish?

```
import sys
from flask import Flask, Response

PORT = 5002
SECONDS = 20

# create app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

@app.route('/wait')
def wait():
    def generate():
        for i in range(SECONDS + 1):
            if i == 0:
                yield "<html><body>Getting data: <pre>"
            import time
            time.sleep(1)
            if i < SECONDS:
                print "tick"
                yield "."
            else:
                yield "Finished after %ss.</pre></body></html>" % SECONDS
    return Response(generate(), mimetype="text/html")

def runserver():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=PORT, threaded=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runserver()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the browser. When I test with Google chrome I get the behaviour described in the question: the second thread doesn't start before the first one has finished.

Testing with:

```
wget -qO- http://localhost:5002/wait
```

I experience the correct response. Each console displays output immediately.